# annotate seaborn pointplot with data values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to attach "values" assocated with each point in the pointplot generated by following code. My code follows below:

```
#data for pointplot with error bars
y = ['SC', 'GA', "FL", "MD"]
x = [.9, 1, 7, 4]
e = [.1, 0, .2, .3]

#plot
ax=sns.pointplot(x,y, join = False)
ax.errorbar(x,y, xerr=e, fmt='o', capsize=5)
ax.axvline(1, color='gray', linestyle='--')

#annotate points
for x,y in zip(x,y):
    ax.text(x, y,str(x),horizontalalignment='center',color='black',weight='light')
sns.despine()
```

The result is shown below[image]

However, my text runs over the data points making the result look clumsy.  How can I move the "values" in text to just above the data points?

Comment: `ax.text(x, y, str(x)+'\n', ...)` would work. As well as `ax.text(x, y+0.2, str(x), ...)`. To have more control, there is [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it works! The second did not. Please post your reply here and I will accept it!

Comment: Oops. The second suggestion only works when y is numerical.